# Android : Where to store my Database : Service or Activity?

Tags: android, database, service, aidl

My program is composed of a **remote service** who in **background download** every 1 hours data from internet and update a database. Then, the service will alert the user for predefined data.

The **activity** is made for **setting the alert settings** and some others parameters. The service should be able to work on his own without the activity.

I **was wondering where to put the sql database** ?

Let's say i create it within the activity, would i be able to access it from the service ?? 
Should i then construct a AIDL connection or i can just access the database by reading it directly (even if the activity is not working) ??

Advice would be appreciate.

Ps : i'm looking for something simple as i'm still a beginner in android ;)

Comment: Does your service need get some information from activity? Or do you want to access database in activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @black crow mentioned if you have Activity and Service in the same process it does not matter where you create your database. If they are separate processes then to my point of view it's better to create database in the Service and also there create methods to access to database data from Activity (for instance, getAllData). Thus, all interactions with database will be in the Service.
If your activity and service in different processes you can also create ContentProvider and, thus, your activity and service will be logically devided (activity will only read data from ContentProvider and Service will push data there). To my point of view this approach will suit all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have service in the same process as Activity, it does not matter where you create it and where you wish to access it. AIDL will be required only when you have a Service running in a separate process.

Comment: My service will start at the startup of the phone. I will only use the activity to set up the service and to show some graphs (with some data from the database). 
I'm not sure how many process that makes.

Comment: But my service and my acticty are defined on the same project (same application).

Comment: As far a I see you are talking about only one process here.